# Association in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

There's a structure of the following format:

```
 (setq dist '(((1 1) 1)
              ((0 2) 3)
              ((1 2) 1)
              ((2 3) 3)
              ((3 5) 4)))
```

Is there any function which, if I call

```
(myf '(0 2))
```

could give me

```
3
```

or

```
((0 2) 3)
```

Something like a reverse `assoc`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fail to see why this would be called a reverse ASSOC.

```
(assoc '(0 2) dist :test #'equal)
> ((0 2) 3)
```

It looks like ASSOC works fine, provided you change the *test* function, so that lists used as keys are correctly tested.

Comment: By the way, if you actually want a "reverse" assoc, i.e., find the pair where the CDR matches, there is RASSOC.